# How to put condition in below RegEx?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a below Regex, which puts '\n' in place of comma(,), only when comma is after (> or @) (Not the next character but anytime after the occurrence of "> or @".

```
$address =~ s/([^@>]+[@>][^,]+),\s*/$1\n/g;
```

Above Regex converts Input to Output as shown below,

Input:

```
$address ="mail1, local<mail1@mail.local>, mail2@mail.local, <mail3@mail.local>, mail4 local<mail4@mail.local>"
```

Output:

```
mail1, local<mail1@mail.local>
mail2@mail.local
<mail3@mail.local>
mail4, local<mail4@mail.local>
```

Now What I am trying to do is, to achieve the same thing but if comma (,) is in between double quotes (") then avoid replacing it with '\n'.

Basically for below Input I am expecting output shown below.

Input:

```
$address = "mail1,local<mail1@mail.local>, \"mail2@,mail.local\"<mail2@mail.local>";
```

Current Output:

```
mail1,local<mail1@mail.local>
"mail2@
mail.local" <mail2@mail.local>
```

Expected Output:

```
mail1,local<mail1@mail.local>
"mail2@,mail.local" <mail2@mail.local>
```

Comment: Can there be escaped backslashes or other escape sequences in the strings? Like `$address = "mail1\\\",local<mail1@mail.local>, \"mail2@,mail.local\"<mail2@mail.local>";`

Comment: Yes there can be escape sequences in the string, Main intention is to replace comma(',) with (\n) if it is found outside double quotes and after (@ or >), Here, this is test program so I have added backslash before double quote, In my actual function there won't be any backslashes.

Comment: As per given input by you, "mail1\\\",local<mail1@mail.local>, Here comma is outside double quote but it is before any occurrence of @ or >, so here comma should not be replaced with \n.

Comment: put the double quote as it is, just need to play with comma with specific condition as mentioned above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that there is a problem with your specification in that `"mail2@,mail.local"<mail2@mail.local>` will be split into `"mail2@` and `mail.local"<mail2@mail.local>` because the comma is after an `@`. This solution does what I think you mean

I suggest that you parse your string into tokens and print each one separately

This solution looks for

- A substring enclosed in `<...>`
- A substring enclosed in `"..."`
- A comma possibly with whitespace on either side
- A string of any other characters

A flag `$seen_email` is set to *true* if the token contains an `@` or a `>`. If the flag is true then any commas are converted to newlines and the flag reset, while anything else is printed verbatim

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $address = 'mail1,local<mail1@mail.local>, "mail2@,mail.local"<mail2@mail.local>';

{   
    my $seen_email;

    while ( $address =~ / \G ( <[^<>]*> | "[^"]*" | \h*,\h* | [^"<>,]+ ) /xg ) {

        my $token = $1;
        $seen_email ||= $token =~ /[\@>]/;

        if ( $seen_email and $tok =~ /^\h*,/ ) {
            $token = "\n";
            $seen_email = undef;
        }

        print $token;
    }
}
```

#### output

```
mail1,local<mail1@mail.local>
"mail2@,mail.local"<mail2@mail.local>
```

#### Update

If you must have a substitution instead of printing the modified string to `STDOUT` then a refactoring of the above solution to an `s///eg` will do that for you

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $address = 'mail1,local<mail1@mail.local>, "mail2@,mail.local"<mail2@mail.local>';

{   
    my $seen_email;

    $address =~ s{ \G ( <[^<>]*> | "[^"]*" | \h*,\h* | [^"<>,]+ ) }{

        my $token = $1;
        $seen_email ||= $tok =~ /[\@>]/;

        if ( $seen_email and $token =~ /^\h*,/ ) {
            $token = "\n";
            $seen_email = undef;
        }

        $token;

    }exg;
}

say $address;
```

#### output

The output is identical